# How to prevent Maven from using a <repository> in a dependency's pom-file?

Tags: maven, repository

By accident we discovered that one of our dependencies (spring-data-jpa 1.1.0.RELEASE, see [its pom-file](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.1.0.RELEASE.pom)) includes a `<repository>`.

This means that our builds directly go to that repository, circumventing our own central Maven repository.

However, we want our builds to be controlled: all artifacts should come from our department's Maven repository, and that we configure to have or get everything we need from the places we want.

*Question:* How can we instruct Maven to ignore `<repositories>` from dependent artifacts' pom-files?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable a repository like this:

```
<repository>
    <id>spring-libs-release</id>
    <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

Or you can try using a `mirrorOf` declaration, to use a [single repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html#Using_A_Single_Repository):

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>internal-repository</id>
        <name>Maven Repository Manager running on repo.mycompany.com</name>
        <url>http://repo.mycompany.com/proxy</url>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Comment: Is there also a way to disable all repositories (except for our own department repository)?  Because that is what would solve my problem, I think.  (The key is that I don't know which repositories are used, and I don't want to regularly manually check our entire tree to find out.)

Comment: I think so-- at least I did not know about this configuration option, and we will look into it.  Thanks!

Comment: If you use a MRM you should use `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>`

Comment: @Stephen Connolly: Thanks for the advice, we will definitely look into this setting. Subtitles for those reading along: MRM = Maven Repository Manager.